# Make click event propagate to peer component which sits inside same FrameLayout, for home widget

Tags: android

I have the following layout design, for my home widget.

[image]

It consists of

1. A green title bar
2. A control button, align `right|center_vertical` in green title bar.
3. A much larger view, overlay `top|right`

The XML looks like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="#ff00ff00">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/control_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sticky_note_widget_button_white_18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_button_selector_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/much_larger_click_area"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#7fff0000" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The control button (`control_button`) has a selector. That's mean, when human click on it, its background will change accordingly.

Since the touch area of the control button is small, we would like to utilize `much_larger_click_area`. We wish `much_larger_click_area` able to propagate its click event, to `control_button`.

`duplicateParentState` option wouldn't help, because `much_larger_click_area` and `control_button` isn't parent-child relationship.

May I know how I can make click event of `much_larger_click_area`, propagate to `control_button`, so that `control_button`'s selector state will change too? 
Note, I'm going to use this layout in home widget. So, I'm pretty limited to `RemoteViews` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should consume the `much_larger_click_area` touch events and use it for `control_button`. I did the same thing before, use below snippet:

```
much_larger_click_area.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    float x = (control_button.getWidth() - control_button.getPaddingRight()) / 2;
    float y = control_button.getHeight() / 2;
    MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
            event.getDownTime(),
            event.getEventTime(),
            event.getAction(),
            x,
            y,
            event.getMetaState()
    );

    control_button.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using RemoteView, not able to provide above functionality.